# How to remove obligation to a car loan

Tags: united-states, auto-loan, missouri

We live in Missouri. My husband refinanced his car loan through an internet loan source.  Then I started getting the invoices for the car loan.  I didn't think anything of it until, my husband decided to voluntarily have the car repossessed.  The Loan company is saying that I am responsible for the deficiency of the loan after they sell it.  Am I responsible? I didn't sign anything. I'm not sure if there was some type of electronic signature my husband entered.

Answer (score 14):

Are you in the middle of a divorce?  If so, please refer this to your divorce attorney.

If not, Missouri is a [separate property state](https://www.debtcollectionanswers.com/in-missouri-husband-worked-died-of-cancer-wife-did-not-sign-any-medical-paperwork-is-wife-liablke-to-repay-medical-debt.html), so you should write them a letter saying that

1. It is not your car.
2. You did not sign or cosign the loan.
3. Missouri is a separate property state, so if they have a business relationship with your husband, they should talk to him.

They should respond to this letter with any proof that they have that you should pay the debt.  E.g. loan documents with something purporting to be your signature.  If they don't and continue to harass you, call the [Missouri state attorney general's office](https://www.ago.mo.gov/about-us/contact-us).  They should either be able to help you or refer you to someone who deals with wrongful debt collection (in case Missouri has a separate department for that).

If your husband faked your signature on something, that would be fraud on his part.  Legally you could have him prosecuted.  You might need to prosecute him in order to legally establish that it's not your signature.  Of course, at this point, you might find yourself in the middle of a divorce.